# How to change ( invert ) color on a high quality photo of a product?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, contrast

There is a black leather with a yellow thread and my client wants me to change it to a medium gray leather with black thread ?
I ve tried many ways but the naturals shadows on the leather where is it close to the tread is impossible (at least for me) to make...[image]

the first image is the closest i could get ( they still want "more" darker thread ) the second is original (black leather)

Comment: Hi user42350, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Ultimately this comes down to you and your client agreeing upon what constitutes a "black stitch". The only possible answer here, I think, is to "darken the stitch".

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do just about anything in Photoshop. Two approaches that I would try would be:

- Duplicate the original, convert to CMYK and apply the yellow channel to the black channel in Multiply mode (`Image > Apply Image`). You could also try simply copying the yellow channel and pasting it on a new layer, using Darken or Darker Color as a blend mode.
- Isolate the yellow thread with `Select > Color Range`, then remove the color with Hue/Saturation (fine tune the mask by hand). Darken the thread with the Burn tool or a black brush in Overlay mode. Keep the opacity low (30% or less) so you can build the effect gradiently. The tricky part is maintaining the texture, but that's going to be a matter of careful brush work and close observation while you're working.

There are probably several more that I'm not thinking of right at the moment. If I saw your original, I might be able to give you better direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use the magic wand, experimenting with settings of how many pixels it is tolerant of to select those areas while holding shift to get multiple selections. Then once all is selected experiment with curves, levels or brightness to get the look you want.